# CSS Transition Fading out but not in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a div that behaves as follows:

When the form input comes into focus, I want the background to become a dark overlay except the form which stays bright. When the form loses focus, I want the overlay to go away.

I have both of these working but I want the appearing and disappearing of the overlay to fade in and out. I tried doing this using transitions and it works for the losing focus part not for the gaining focus part; it doesn't fade in but rather just appears. I have no idea why. Could someone explain why this is happening and also what might be a better way to go about doing this.

Note: This won't work on Safari and I only care to make it work for Chrome right now. Also, I would rather not use JQuery so please limit your answers to raw js.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/31g18rqm/) is a JSFiddle.

```
 `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically `display:none` and `block` is not support transition so you can use `height` for get it same.

Working fiddle **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31g18rqm/1/)**

Update css part

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 0.4s linear; /* Add this */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.hidden {
  height: 0;   /* Add this */
  display: none;  /* remove */
}

#submit-form {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;  /* Add this */
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#submit-form");
const formInput = document.querySelector("#submit-input");
const overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay");

formInput.addEventListener("focus", () => {
  console.log("here");
  form.classList.add("above-overlay");
  overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
  overlay.classList.remove("faded");
});

formInput.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  overlay.classList.add("faded");
  form.classList.remove("above-overlay");
});

// Need to wait till fade out is finished before removing overlay
overlay.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
  // only in case where we are removing overlay
  if (overlay.classList.contains("faded")) {
    overlay.classList.add("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#overlay.faded {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.above-overlay {
  z-index: 11;
}

.hidden {
  height: 0;
}

#submit-form {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="overlay" class="hidden faded"></section>

<p>
  This is a sample first paragraph. In his autobiography Surely you’re joking, Mr. Feynman, Richard Feynman discusses his “different box of tools”. Among other things, he mentions a tool he picked up from the text Advanced Calculus by Woods, of differentiating
  under the integral sign – “it’s a certain operation... that’s not taught very much in the universities”. It seems some things haven’t changed in the way calculus is taught, since I was never exposed to this trick in classes either. However, I’ve accidentally
  stumbled upon several elegant applications of the maneuver, and thought I’d write a couple of them down.
</p>


<form id="submit-form">
  Sample form:
  <input id="submit-input" type="text">
</form>


<p>
  An old problem is to extend the factorial function to non-integer arguments. This was resolved by Euler, who discovered two formulas for n! (one an integral, the other an infinite product) which make sense even when n is not an integer. We derive one
  of Euler’s formulas by employing the trick of differentiating under the integral sign.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the functional answer! Some explanation would be lovely. I'm guessing the `display:none` invalidates the animation?

Comment: yes `display` property does not support the transition effect so you can use `height` property to get it and i did the same. you can check answer.

Comment: Ah makes sense. Firstly, could I ask then why you changed the transition from `opacity` to `all` and added a transition to the .faded css property too. It works without this too? Secondly, is this a good way to do what I'm trying to do or is there a better way?

Comment: yes i change it because i need to transition on height and opacity both so i used it you can use `,` also to get the same. just like `height 0.4s linear, opacity 0.4s linear`